# What's wrong with this mysqli query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my mysqli code below. The data is definitely in the table. I have 2  questions:

1. Why isn't this giving me any results?
2. Could I have the echo `<table></table>` section in a separate php file, if yes, how would I call `$name,$partner,$cell` etc.?

   ```
     <?php

     $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $uname, $pword, $db);
   if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
   {
   echo "Connection failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error;
   exit();
   }

     $query = ("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contacttype IN ('Buyer','Seller','Buyer / Seller','Investor') AND leadstatus = 'New' ORDER BY date DESC");

     $result = $mysqli->query($query);

     while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

     $space = (!empty($row['firstname']) && !empty($row['lastname'])) ? ' ' : '';        
     $name = $row['firstname'].$space.$row['lastname'];       
     $partner  = $row['spousefirst'];   
     $cell = (!empty($row['phonecell'])) ? " {$row['phonecell']} (cell)" : ''; 
     $email = (!empty($row['email'])) ? " {$row['email']} (email)" : '';
     $ID = $row['ID'];

     echo'<table>
     <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="<? echo $ID; ?>"></td>
       <td><a href="/backend/leads/view/?ID=<? echo $ID; ?> "><strong><? echo $name; ?></strong></a></td>
       <td><a href="/backend/leads/view/?ID=<? echo $ID; ?> "><? echo $partner; ?></a></td>
       <td><? echo $phonecell; ?></td>
       <td><a href="mailto:<? echo $email; ?>"><? echo $email; ?></a></td>
       <td><? echo date("M jS, g:i A", strtotime($date)); ?></td>
       <td><? echo $contacttype; ?></td>
       <td><? echo $agentassigned; ?></td>
       <td><? echo $leadstatus; ?></td>
       <td><a href="/backend/contacts/notes.php?ID=<? echo $ID; ?>">View </a>+ </td>
       <td><a href="/backend/contacts/todo.php?ID=<? echo $ID; ?>">View </a>+ </td>
       <td><a href="/backend/contacts/deletesuccess.php?ID=<? echo $ID; ?>">D</a></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>';
        }
        ?>
   ```

EDIT:

It's showing the `<table>` but just not giving me values for $name, $email...ect.

Comment: try echoing errors. e.g.:`$query = ("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contacttype IN ('New','Buyer','Seller','Buyer / Seller','Investor') AND leadstatus = 'New' ORDER BY date DESC") or die(mysql_error);` See: http://forums.devarticles.com/mysql-development-50/mysql-where-in-function-2031.html

Comment: Are you sure the query results anything? Have you tried to execute in MySQL command line/phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Trying breaking up the query and making sure the expected data is present in table.

Comment: the data is definitely in the table!

Comment: ('New','Buyer','Seller','Buyer /Seller','Investor') are these table field names? if so, you need to use ` instead of '

Comment: You should be using numeric values representing a foreign key for identifying types, statuses etc - anything with a finite list of possible options. You then create a separate table to hold the string representations of these values, which you can `JOIN` onto if you want those strings in your results. This will make your database queries more efficient, and also prevent you from not getting results because of incorrect casing/charset/whitespace/whatever - and I'm guessing one of those what's causing your current problem.

Comment: @DaveRandom - you lost me, I'm just a beginner :)

Comment: @Josh What I mean is that you are storing the strings `New`, `Buyer` etc in your `contacttype` field, similarly you are storing strings like `New` in `leadstatus`. What you should do instead is allocate those statuses numeric representations (`New = 1, Buyer = 2` etc) and create a table called e.g. `statuses` where you store a map of numeric ID -> string title representations. In your `contacts` table you would change the columns to `INT` type, and use that column to map types. This means that all searches are just using these numbers and you are not subject to string problems like case etc

Comment: @DaveRandom - `New` in `contacttype` is a mistake, I've fixed above. `New` is only in `leadstatus`. Thanks for explaining that. Please see edit in my post.

Comment: @Usman - I did that and I'm just getting a blank page. I checked the table, there is definitely data in there.

Comment: @ZombieHunter - Yes, I got 5 results. Not sure why I'm getting a blank screen.

Comment: @DavidPassmore - did that, no error..just a screen with check boxes for all 5 entries in table, but not values are showing for `$name` `$partner`, etc.

Comment: @Josh [Here is an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e617/1) of how you do stuff like this using foreign keys (references to the primary key of another table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final echo does not look well constructed. I would prefer to use a concatenated string to output the variables, just like this( I put only a few lines as example):

```
echo'<table>
<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="'. $ID .'"></td>
     <td><a href="/backend/leads/view/?ID='. $ID .'"><strong>'. $name.' </strong></a></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

The query looks solid as does the rest of your code. Here are a few troubleshooting steps to try out:

1. `echo` out `$query` and run it directly against your database. Do you get results? If you don't get any results from a direct query then that means the query is returning  0 rows and your tables will end up empty as well.
2. Do a `var_dump($result)` to verify there is information being stored in there. You could also add change `$result = $mysqli->query($query);` to `$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die $mysqli->error;`

The results from these 2 steps should give you a good idea on where things are going wrong. In general you want to stop through each part of the query process and look at every variable involved to ensure that it has the data you expect stored inside of it.

To answer your 2nd question: yes you can. If you put the code for the table in a separate file and then `include()`it, the variables will still be available to the included code.

See the PHP manual on [include()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: you mean just do `echo $query` after $query? I'm learning! I tried $query in the query window and got 5 results.

Comment: Thanks, I tried both suggestions and still not getting anything. The query is returning 5 rows except there is nothing in them `$name` `$partner`, etc. Any other suggestions?